# What's the min/max value of basic datatypes in R?

Tags: r

the basic datatypes in R language are:
**logical
numeric
integer
character
Double
Complex
Raw**
but in can't find what's the max/min value of any datatypes written, anyone could help me pls?

Comment: look at `.Machine` for most of them. not that these values are machine-dependent. raw is `0:127` (or maybe 255? check `as.raw(128)`). character doesn't really have a range? not sure what you mean. complex is a pair of doubles.

Comment: thanks a lot, for "character" my question is what's the max characters that is it permitted for the string?